# Mount ext3fs in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, ext3

I'm surprised I couldn't find this question trough the search. What's the easiest/best way to mount an ext3 formatted partition in Windows (7 RC, in this case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found [this overview](http://www.howtoforge.com/access-linux-partitions-from-windows) of three ways to access an ext3 partition.  Don't know if the first supports Windows 7; the second supports Vista so it likely does.  Both of those are just file managers, though.

The third, [Ext2 IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html), is the only one I've heard of before, and it does support ext3.  It sounds like you wanted the partition mounted so all apps can access it, and that's what this does.

Answer (score 4):

I found various answers for Windows in general with [this search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ext3+windows). ["Four Applications for Accessing Ext3 Partitions From Windows"](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2008/03/19/four-applications-for-accessing-ext3-partitions-from-windows/) looks like the most comprehensive look at it - from having spent 30 seconds on each of a few results.

I don't know whether any of them will work with Windows 7, mind you. [This guide](http://www.go2linux.org/accessing-linux-drive-ext-with-vista) is for Vista, and I suspect Windows 7 is similar enough to Vista for that to be at least worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one possible way is to run Windows inside VirtualBox on Linux and configure directories to be shared.

(Disclaimer: I've only ever done this the other way around. Disclosure: I work for the producers of VirtualBox, but do not work on it.)